# Eating 7-8 meals for build muscle but loose fat. How?

Tags: bellyfat

I am trying to loose my belly fat, around my waist and i came across [Kris's 12 week program](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/kris-gethin-12-week-daily-trainer.html), I eat like 5-6 meals a day. But i don't get the science of eating so much, when eating so much is the reason you get fat. Its been 2 weeks and i have seen my weight got down 4.5 kg but my waist is 35. I am 5.8 and age 29. I guess in BMI i am under overweight. 
So my question is, how should i know, i should eat this much. Like i make 0.5kg of chicken breasts but how do i know how much to eat in each meal? And what if someone who can't make steaks, find broccoli or sweet potato. What else should i eat as i am eating whole lots of chicken every meal.

Comment: The two things I didn't like in Kris's 12 week program is that there wasn't any discussion on portion sizes (that I could see), and the reliance on supplements.  He does have a product to sell of course.  LarrisaGodzilla's answer is very good about explaining that it's the same amount of food, just distributed throughout the day in a way that works for you.  You'll be surprised how much you can eat to loose weight if you stay away from burgers, fries, and other classically unhealthy foods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question you should ask yourself is not 'how?' but 'why?'

The 'science of eating so much', as you put it, is non-existing. Whatever you put into your body will be digested and used as your body sees fit. Everything your body can't use right away, will be 'queued' and used later on. So it doesn't matter if you eat 8 fistfuls of food each day or if you have on huge meal every evening.

This is supported by many people losing weight (or building muscle) using an intermitten fasting (IF) diet. During an IF-diet you're basically fasting 16 hours and only eat during an 8-hour window. So ask yourself, if your body could only use up so much during 8 hours, how do these people reach their goals? They do, because meal timing *doesn't matter*.

So back to the question you should ask yourself: Why would I want to eat 6-8 meals a day?
Well, it depends mostly on lifestyle. If you *like* eating 6-8 meals a day, by all means, go ahead. If you want to eat 3, 4 or 5 meals a day, that's also cool. The takeaway point here is to make it work *for you*. While 6-8 meals the size of a fist might work for Kris Gethin, it might not work for you. So find what works and stick to it, because the only diet that works is the on that you can pull through.

On to meal preparation: The portion size should be more obvious to you once you adjust the meal frequency to what you're used to, so I'll not go into that as much. Considering you're eating 'whole lots' of chicken meat every meal, there are some alternatives you could use. Some foods I wouldn't want to miss on a diet:

- High protein: Chicken, poultry, fish
- Complex carbs: Brown rice, whole-grain pasta, sweet potatoes
- Healthy fats: Almonds, nuts, vegetable oils, fish (again)

Of course you can always add vegetables like carrots, broccoli, tomatoes, cucumbers and also fruit in reasonable amounts.

Some last words on the workout. A 5-day-split is suboptimal for most people, as you're training each muscle group only once per week. For that to be effective, you'd have to have a very high-intensity only a few people can keep up. I'd rather to 2-3 full body workouts per week and add in some cardio, but that's just me. In the end it has to (again) work for you. Just wanted to mention it.

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer and I couldn't agree more.   I think the results are pretty much in on nutrient timing.  I suppose one caveat would be people like Michael Phelps, Jay Cutler, or Rich Froning who eat 10k+ calories a day and physically can't fit that quantity of food into their body unless they spread it out throughout the day.  But those people are freaks. :)

Comment: The only part where I cringed was when I saw, *'or if you have one huge meal every evening.'*

Comment: @jp2code: It does sound like binge-eating, doesn't it? But I've heard of people doing just that. Granted, for _losing_ weight it might be a very bad strategy and a slightly exaggerated example.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla Thanks for detailed answer. I noticed my weight back to as it was before joining the gym. 79 kg, i went to 74.5 kg. Although i see my arms getting bigger and shoulders getting broad, but no effect i see on belly. Its almost a month, should i be worried?

Comment: @Nofel: The mirror (or photos) isn't very realiable when it comes to seeing the small changes. If you haven't taken measurements (arms, shoulder, waist etc.) yet, I would recommend that. It's much more reliable for tracking progress than 'guessing' in the mirror. Maybe you will find that you are losing belly fat this way.